# How to mange inventory tables for a hotel booking system in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

[image] 
Hi am working on a hotel booking system. Where admin can add multiple hotels and multiple rooms for each hotel. 

But right now i am stuck in inventory management. For every room there will be 3 type of inventories

1. **Master inventory** : here admin can add number of room available for a particular type of room (Eg: Suite room) Sunday to Saturday. Available room count will be different in each days.
2. **Periodic inventory** : Here admin can choose starting date and ending date and number of room available in between those date's.
3. **Daily inventory** : Here admin can choose a date and number of available rooms in that particular date.

And priority order for inventory selection will be 3 -> 2 -> 1. 
ie. When user select a date in website and search for hotels. First check in **daily inventory** if there is a **daily inventory** found then and its match for the user requirement then will proceed further. 
Else if there is no daily inventory then will check for periodic inventory and If **periodic inventory** not found then will check for **master inventory**. 

 
For every room there will be a master inventory but periodic and daily inventory are optional. And in master inventory you can give available rooms from Sunday to Saturday ie. for 7 days in a week. Same for periodic inventory.

Right now i am trying to implement it like this

### Room table

```
ID integer
HOTEL_ID integer
ROOM_NAME varchar
INV_SUN integer
INV_MON integer
INV_TUE integer
.
.
INV_SAT integer
PERIODIC_STAR_DATE Date
PERIODIC_END_DATE Date
PERIODIC_SUN integer
PERIODIC_MON integer
.
.
PERIODIC_SAT integer
```

I don't know the method i following is correct and i have no idea how to mange daily inventory. 
As of now it is really difficult to search availability for hotels. 

Please advice me how to redesign the database in a better way.

Comment: your concept is not correct. Weekly, daily all these can be displayed with one select query. Let me design this database for you. Please wait

Answer (score 4):

Here is your answer:
[image]
This design states that:

1. There are many hotels
2. Each hotel have many room types e.g. suite, 2 beds, 3 beds etc.
3. Each room type contains the rooms that have isBooked integer i.e. 0 or 1
4. Finally there is Booking table that stores specific hotel different rooms data

Now you can make queries e.g.

1. Which type of rooms in which hotels are reserved
2. How many rooms are booked
3. What rooms are booked for specific hotel from this date to this date
4. How many rooms are empty
5. Which type of rooms for which hotel are empty or reserved

so on and so forth. You can make numerous queries but this 4 tables are enough to meet your requirements in all respect

**Update:**

5. Admins table  have different admin roles. Each admin will manage a hotel, its room_type, rooms and booking
   **Update-2**
   [image]

   **Update-3:**
   [image]

Comment: i am ok with the method you suggested. I can calculate room availability by comparing with Booking table in this method. But I need to give admin a option to store available number of rooms between two dates, like from 1st December to 30th December only 10 suite room will be available to book out of 30 suite room. Same for Daily inventory: on 25th December only 5 room available out of 30 suite rooms.

Comment: You can add one admin table with some fields e.g. name, login, password and connect to hotels table

Comment: I am still not clear about managing periodic and daily inventories which admin can change from his side. Especially for daily inventory

Comment: let me update database design because you not mentioned anything about admin in your question that's why I not added there. wait plz I am going to update my answer

Comment: I added some comments more to describe admins table underneath Update

Comment: if need more explanation let me know please

Comment: @Joe please explain more what you are looking for

Comment: You said: I am still not clear about managing periodic and daily inventories which admin can change from his side. Especially for daily inventory. The reply is: admin can mark a room in rooms table isBook (0 or 1) zero will be empty and 1 will be book also admin can generate different reports e.g. how many rooms are booked from this date to this date etc.

Comment: i am just add screenshots of how  my user interface looks like.  Please check it, i need the table structure to manage these 3 type of inventories.  And Ghayel i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97727/discussion-between-ghayel-and-joe).

Comment: I started chat here. Please attend it to discuss further

Comment: In master inventory you have all rooms whereas in periodic inventory you are allocating some quantity of rooms for different days. In daily inventory you are displaying table to book room. is that right before going a head?

Comment: waiting for your reply to finalize it

Comment: Master inventory is the base inventory. In periodic inventory admin can enter number of available rooms between two dates, and between these dates master inventory will override by periodic inventory. And if any inventory change in a particular date, admin can use daily inventory where admin can enter available number of rooms in that particular date. So master and periodic inventory will be override my daily inventory in that particular date. this is what i need to convert into tables.

Comment: I updated design as update-2: please check and let me know if you have any question

Comment: let me know if you still need anything else

Comment: I am ok with your update. but how will mange daily inventory here? please add it too.

Comment: you said==>`So master and periodic inventory will be override my daily inventory in that particular date. this is what i need to convert into tables.` I left deliberately for you to go a head and if there was any help. I am here. By the way you neither marked my answer or voted up

Comment: Hi already voted up your answer. And i really appreciate your help. But i can't mark your answer as correct because still i am not got the exact solution for my problem. I need to manage daily inventory too, in your diagram i can't see table for storing daily inventory. I tried the similar table structures you suggested before but the complexity of my application is not reduced. My one of the main problem in managing 'daily' inventory and  its still not solved.

Comment: just add date column in daily inventory